# how to include main navigation twice with different display

Tags: theming, 8, navigation

i started working with drupal 8 few days ago. 
I am working on theming with Twig.
I included the main Navigation on the header, after the activation of twig debug mode , i followed the suggestion of twig and i created menu-main.html.twig contains the html respresentation of the links and i had this display:
[image]
My Problem is :
I included the Main navigation on the footer too but it appears the same way as the header but i want to change the display to be like this:
[image]
What should i do ?

Comment: Add the main menu *block* to different regions. Then style accordingly based on region class specificity. This isn't exactly what you asked for, and it's my opinion on how I would build a maintainable Drupal web site.

Comment: the problem is , i already created a twig file that define the menu (not the default one on /templates/navigation/menu.html.twig so the <ul> an <li> tags take the css class definied under that file

Comment: You can change it back?

Comment: Yes i can but it will change the display of the menus on the header

Answer (score -1):

Don't rely on a hardcoded class in your overridden template to style the menu, but instead rely on a container to style it (for example the containing block or region).